# Why is my proof on 5 is the non-residue of primes in the form of $5k+2$ incorrect?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

According to Gauss's Lemma, , $\left(\frac{m}{p}\right)$=$(-1)^u$, where
$u$ is the cardinality of the set $\{ma\mid 1\le a\le \frac{1}{2}(p-1), \text{ the least positive residues mod }p \text{ of } \ ma \ge \frac{1}{2} p\}$

Therefore, $\frac{1}{2} p\le5a\lt p$，$\frac{3p}{2}\le5a\lt 2p$ and $a$ is an integer

Therefore, $\cfrac p{10}+1$ $\le a\le \cfrac p5$, and  $\cfrac{3p}{10}+1\le a\le \cfrac{2p}5$

Therefore, $u=[\cfrac p5]+[\cfrac{2p}5]-[\cfrac{p}{10}]-[\cfrac{3p}{10}]$          , [a] = biggest integer less or euqal than a

Since $p$ is the form of $5k+2$, $u=[\cfrac{(5k+2)}5]+[\cfrac{(10k+4)}5]-[\cfrac{(5k+2)}{10}]-[\cfrac{(15k+6)}{10}]$

If $k$ is odd, $u=k+2k-[\cfrac k2]-\left(k+[\cfrac k2]+1\right)$ and $[\cfrac k2]=\cfrac{(k-1)}2$, so $u=k$, which is odd

If $k$ is even, $u=k+2k-[\cfrac k2]-\left(k+[\cfrac k2]\right)$ and $[\cfrac k2]=\cfrac{k}2$ ,so u=k ,which is even

However, $u$ should always be odd when $p$ is the form of $5k+2$, so why is this proof incorrect?

Comment: I have hopefully edited it correctly, not sure though because the original formatting was so out-of-place.

Comment: @AlexK Don't use bullets for multiplication. If you *really* can't use juxtaposition, then use `\cdot` to produce a dot. Compare `2\cdot p`, $2\cdot p$, with `2\bullet p`: $2\bullet p$. The former is far preferable to the latter.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that k cannot be even since p is odd prime. So 5 is the non-residue of odd primes in the form of 5k+2.

Comment: I see that if $k$ is even, so too will $5k+2$ be even.  Since you have posted a self-answer, I'll have to assume this somehow resolves the Question in your mind.  Even so, be wary of posting an "answer" that is significantly shorter than the Question it responds to.  Our goal is to collect and curate content that will help future Readers as well as yourself.